# Relations between the various Divisor Groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

For a variety $X$ there are various groups one can attach to it pertaining divisors:

- Pic(X), line bundles (with group structure given by tensor product)
- Ca(X), Cartier divisors modulo principal divisors
- Cl(X), Weil divisors modulo linear equivalence
- CH$^1$(X), Weil divisors modulo rational equivalence.

What are the relations between these various groups?
If one starts moving away from smoothness of $X$, can we understand how they differ?

(also, I always thought the last two were equal by definition but I've seen stated that when $X$ is non-normal they can differ: could someone clear this up for me?)